# Как построить график внутри QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, pyqt, matplotlib, qt-designer, qgraphicsview

Как с использованием *matplotlib* построить график внутри *PyQt* виджета `QGraphicsView`? 
Прошу подскажите или направьте, не могу разобраться как это делается?

Ui:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(249, 332)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 249, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Код:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Ui_unt import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TEST(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graph)

    def graph(self):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = TEST()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю почему вы выбрали `QGraphicsView` для размещения графика,
но пусть будет так и выглядит это примерно так:

```
import sys
import random                                                                     # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure                                              # +++
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas  # +++


#from Ui_unt import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(249, 332)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 249, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        

class TEST(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graph)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.gca()
        self.axes.set_title("My Plot")        

    def graph(self):
#        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
#        y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        
        x = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(10) ]
        y = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(10) ]
        
        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot(x, y, "-k", label="График внутри виджета QGraphicsView")

        self.axes.legend()
        self.axes.grid(True) 

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.proxy_widget = self.scene.addWidget(self.canvas) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = TEST()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за помощь! А как можно сделать так, чтобы график заполнялся по размеру QGraphicsView?

Comment: @modniyTIGR пожалуйста. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите свой код и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.